# When i add a div element to the page it loose focus an scroll to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link when its clicked a div containing form elements are added to the page.
The problem is when the list become longer. when i add an element to the end of the page, the page focus back to the top making the user to scroll back to the end of the page. How can I prevent it? I tried to use `$(this).focus();` but it didn't work.

```
$("a[id^=link_add_section_]").live('click',function() { // create a section

                var sectionId = $(this).attr('id');
                var sectionIdSplit = sectionId.split('_');
                addSection(sectionIdSplit[3],'groupby');
                $(this).focus();
                alert(1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an id to your anchor

```
<a href="#something" id="myAnchor">Something</a>
```

Bind a click event and prevent default

```
$("#myAnchor").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have "new_div_1" as id of the newly adding div and to move focus to the newly added div, you can do

```
$("body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#new_div_1').offset().top }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to scroll the window to the place of that div:

```
 window.scrollTo(0,$("#MY_DIV").offset().top);
```